# What does the attribute 'reminderEnabled' do on the reminders DocuSign API?

Tags: docusignapi

I think that the text under envelopes->getNotificationSettings->reminder->reminderEnabled is incorrect and feels like a copy & paste error on DocuSign. Anyone know what this means?  Essentially, i'm trying to send out a reminder right away of an envelope.

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/v2/reference/envelopes/envelopes/getnotificationsettings/

[image: reminderEnabled text]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right - it is a copy pasting error. [The correct definition is in the v2.1 Documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/getnotificationsettings/)

> When true, reminders are enabled. The default value is false.

When you create and send an Envelope, it should notify the recipient immediately. Are you intending to send a reminder along with it?